# How to check whether given IP address is in use or not

Tags: bash

How to check whether given IP address is in use or not without using ping utility on Linux and using bash script.

I am trying use nmap command for this so is there any better alternative.

Thanks,
Prashant Ghorpade

Comment: Look for `fping`

Comment: Are you interested in local (LAN) or global (WAN) addresses?

Comment: Please have a look at very similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/593857/how-to-check-if-internet-ip-address-is-currently-taken

Comment: I have tried fping but not using it due to licensing. I am looking for local address only. sudo nmap  -sn -n ip_address | grep 'Host is up'  this looks good?